# How to write 'select max(AdvID) from Advertisement' query in ejb method?

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0, jpql

I don't know how to write when it returns max ID. Please Give me answer.

I have written this in sessionbean but it returns -1.

```
@Override
    public int searchMaxAdvID() {
        int adid=em.createNativeQuery("select max(AdvID) from Advertisement").getMaxResults();
        return adid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you misinterpreted getMaxResults-method. It does not have any connection to the `MAX` function. As said in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getMaxResults%28%29), it should behave following way:

> The maximum number of results the query object was set to retrieve.
>   Returns Integer.MAX_VALUE if setMaxResults was not applied to the
>   query object.

In your case it seems to return -1 instead of Integer.MAX_VALUE. This is clearly incorrect. For example Hibernate 3.6.8.Final returns Integer.MAX_VALUE (2147483647) as specified. Method setMaxResults limit maximum number of rows returned by query.

In your case [getSingleResult](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult%28%29) is right method to use. If there is not any rows in table, result will be null.

```
Integer x = (Integer) em.createNativeQuery(
      "select max(AdvID) from Advertisement").getSingleResult();
```

If there is not specific reason to use native query, use JPQL query as suggested in Nayan Wadekar's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below regular JPQL query rather than using native query.

```
Integer maxAdvId = (Integer) em.createQuery("SELECT MAX(a.advID) from Advertisement a").getSingleResult();
```